# Is there a C++ Almanac?

Tags: java, c++

some of you may know the  Java Almanac : http://www.exampledepot.com/ where a lot of code snippets exist for a day-to-day use.(like reading a file etc.)
I'm currently using C++ and i was just curios if there exists something similar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some good examples and tutorials on the [Josuttis](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/idx.html) site.
The examples are from the The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference book.

Answer (score 1):

[www.java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com), despite it's name, has a number of nice C++ cross-referenced code samples, check the **C++** & **C++ Tutorial** sections.

As a side note some of the examples are borrowed from Josuttis' book.